# Why firefox chooses 2x picture when chrome chooses 1x when devicePixelRatio is 1.25?

Tags: html, image, firefox, chromium, srcset

When choosing between 1x and 2x:
Firefox will load 2x if devicePixelRatio < 1
Chromium will load 2x if devicePixelRatio < 1.5
*Not sure how to test this in Safari as devicePixelRatio doesn't change when I scale website*

Is there really no standard about this? Can't really find out any docs or something on MDN at least... I am sure I am not the only who is interested in this issue.

I am curious because my pictures look really bad in chrome browsers. The only workaround I see is using my x2 pictures under x1.5 pixel density descriptor.

Note: And this is website where you can test browser's behaviour about this feature: https://webkit.org/demos/srcset/

Answer (score 1):

The [`srcset` specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/images.html#selecting-an-image-source) states that the image source may be chosen from a `srcset` "in an implementation-defined manner".

You can find the implementation of Gecko's (the rendering engine Firefox uses) source selection algorithm as of the writing of this answer [here](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/f7edb0b474a1a922f3285107620e802c6e19914d/dom/base/ResponsiveImageSelector.cpp#L347-L349). Note the comment explaining how it works:

> ```
> // Per spec, "In a UA-specific manner, choose one image source"   
> // - For now, select the lowest density greater than displayDensity, otherwise
> //   the greatest density available
> ```

As for [Blink (Chrome)'s implementation](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/refs/heads/main/Source/core/html/parser/HTMLSrcsetParser.cpp#329), when the device pixel ratio is > 1, it tries to use the geometric mean of each pair of candidates to try to select one that is nearest to the device pixel ratio.

Comment: I hope there will be intervention on this behaviour. Thank you.
I guess I will award you a bounty in 4 days.